# Can I use properties from Organization on Corporation schema?

Tags: schema.org

Here is a screenshot of the schema.org website saying that `Corporation` is like a child of `Organization`:

[image]

I see the `keywords` property on `Organization`.

Can I use the `keywords` property on [`Corporation`](https://schema.org/Corporation) as well?

The reason why I am asking is a validator iI am using is giving me an error on this:

[image]

But when I use https://validator.schema.org/, it’s not giving me an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes:

1. The [`keywords`](https://schema.org/keywords) property is defined for [`Organization`](https://schema.org/Organization).
2. Every [`Corporation`](https://schema.org/Corporation) is also an `Organization`.

Which is also why the `keywords` property is listed in the table on https://schema.org/Corporation. You can always stick to that table to see which properties are defined/expected.

(By the way, there aren’t any restrictions for which types Schema.org properties can be used. It’s not an error to use a property for an item of a type for which it’s not defined. It might not be expected/supported by consumers, including validators, and it might not make sense, but it’s not that your structured data would become invalid or something like that.)